# Pass this value from a list with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following list:

```
<ul>
    <li onclick="populateComment(..this.)">very good </li>
    <li onclick="populateComment(..this.)">not so good</li>
    <li onclick="populateComment(..this.)">no t.....</li>
</ul>
```

and javascript:

```
function populateComment() {

    document.getElementById("COMMENT").value = document.getElementById("COMMENT").value + 'THE_STRING_VALUE_FROM_THE_LIST';

}
```

So the idea is that I have a textarea, which I fill by clicking on the list.

So if I click on the first list, the text "**very good**" should be appended to the textarea. But I dont want to retype the text "**very good**" in my function, can I take it directly with something as an argument like `this.value..` so it automatically takes the string between the `<li> ...</li>`

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for:

```
this.textContent || this.innerText
```

[`this.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.textContent) is supported in all decent browsers, `this.innerText` is needed for older versions of IE.

Instead of duplicating the onclick handler multiple times, you can also bind a listener to the `<ul>` element:

```
// Replace <ul> with <ul id="populatefrom">
document.getElementById("populatefrom").onclick = function(ev) {
    ev = ev || window.event; //Backwards compatible with IE
    var target = ev.target;
    if (target.nodeName.toLowerCase() == "li") {
        document.getElementById("COMMENT").value += target.textContent || target.innerText;
    }
};
```

Comment: @Adnan Updated answer for an easier implementation. I have used the simple `.onclick = ..` form to prevent having to define conditions for `addEventListener` (decent browsers) or `attachEvent` (IE).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have anything other than a simple bit of text, you could also use:

```
this.firstChild.nodeValue;
```

However if there are any nodes at all (bold, span, or anything else other than text... even an HTML comment) then this won't work and you need the `textContent/innerText` combo Rob W gave.

Answer (score -1):

Sure you could do this with jQuery like so (didn't test this yet):

```
<ul>
    <li class="populateComment">very good </li>
    <li class="populateComment">not so good</li>
    <li class="populateComment">no t.....</li>
</ul>
```

and your jQuery:

```
$('.populateComment').click(function(){
  $('#textboxID').val($(this).html());
});
```

Working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zEaam/

Comment: -1 for bringing in jQuery just for something so incredibly basic.

Comment: Also, if you're using jQuery, you'd better make full use of it: `$("li").click(function(){$("#textboxId").val($(this).html());});`